# Does Least Squares Regression Minimize the RMSE?

Tags: least-squares, linear-regression, mean-square-error

In the application of least-squares regression to data fitting, the quantity of minimization is the sum of squares (sum of squared errors, to be specific). I believe this fitting also minimizes the root-mean-square error because square root is a monotonic function. However, I was not able immediately to find published sources stating this.

Does anyone disagree with me, i.e., is there a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: write down the underlying minimization problems

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  As you know, the [least-squares estimate minimizes the sum of the squares of the errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Problem_statement), also called the [mean-squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).  In symbols, if $\hat Y$ is a vector of $n$ predictions generated from a sample of $n$ data points on all variables, and $Y$ is the vector of observed values of the variable being predicted, then the mean-squared error is
$$\text{MSE} = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \hat{Y_i})^2.$$

The [root-mean-square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) is $\sqrt{\text{MSE}}$.  Because, as you state, square root is an increasing function, the least-squares estimate also minimizes the root-mean-square error.